# How do I add a class to an HTML element using ElementTree?

Tags: python, html, elementtree

I'm trying to use ElementTree to create an html element with a class, like so:

```
nextLink = ElementTree.SubElement(root_element, "a", class="bah",href="www.bah.com")
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I think it's because 'class' is a reserved keyword in Python. If I change the spelling or case of class it works, but that doesn't fix my problem as I need the output to be 'class'.

Is there a workaround?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pass in a dict of 'attrib': 'value' pairs

```
nextLink = ElementTree.SubElement(
    root_element, 'a',
    {
        'class': 'bah',
        'href': 'www.bah.com'
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
nextLink.set('class', 'bah')
```